# What do the cursor options do? Like; cursorline, cursorcolumn, cursoropts

Tags: cursor

#### Background

I was looking to change the shape of my cursor, the thing that tells you where you are, like the i-beam on this site.

Instead I got these options which highlight text, I don't know the use of this as we have visual highlight and visual line, so what are the functions of these options?

Comment: try the help: `:h 'cursorline'`, `:h 'cursorcolumn'` (don't know what `cursoropts` is supposed to be)

Comment: I know what they do, they just highlight the current line you're on, I don't understand the use

Comment: The use is that they highlight the line or column in which your cursor is. Makes it easier to find in a screen full of text. If you don't find that helpful, it's okay. Leave them off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help 'cursorline'` tells Vim to highlight the current line, which may or may not help you keep context as you move around. Enable the feature if you find it useful.

`:help 'cursorcolumn'` is basically the same but for the current column. Again, enable it if you think it is useful to you.

Those features differ from visual mode in that a) they don't require a conscious effort from the user for the highlighting to take place, and b) they are not related to editing.

There's no such thing as `:help 'cursoropts'` in Vim.

If you want to change the shape of the cursor, this site has plenty of relevant threads: https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?q=cursor+shape.

Comment: ah ok so that's all there is to it, thought there might've been more, thanks.